# response redirect previous page classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, response.redirect

I want to go back one of several possible pages if the captcha was entered incorrectly on the referring page. This is what I am trying and it just bypasses the redirect when there is an error and takes them to the success page. If I put in   response.redirect("somepage.asp") it works no problem but i need it to handle multiple page referers

```
Call ValidateCAPTCHA()
If m_CAPTCHAPASS<>1 then
Session("ValidCAPTCHA")="false"
Dim redirectpage
redirectpage = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") & "e=1" 
Session("FirstName")=Request.Form("First_Name")
Session("Phone")=Request.Form("Phone")
Session("EMail")=Request.Form("EMail")
Session("Comments")=Request.Form("Comments")
response.redirect(Request.redirectpage)
end if
'send email script follows
```

Comment: Can u verify what's inside of `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")` ? Just output it to the page.

Comment: Ok I found my mistake....with the referrer appending e=1 should have been ?e=1...now the issue is that after multiple submissions with the wrong captcha it keeps appending parameters:
http://www.somesite.com/referringpage.asp?e=1
then becomes
http://www.somesite.com/referringpage.asp?e=1?e=1
and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your comment, to prevent multiple parameter addition, just check if parameter already added. Something like:

```
Dim redirectpage

redirectpage = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") 
If Right(redirectpage, 4) <> "?e=1" Then redirectpage = redirectpage & "?e=1"
'.... the rest of the code
```